# Trying to reproduce a dechex() function behaviour on x64 architecture

Tags: php, 64-bit, hex, base-conversion

The example #2 of the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) of the `dechex()` function is the following :

```
// The output below assumes a 32-bit platform.
// Note that the output is the same for all values.
echo dechex(-1)."\n";
echo dechex(PHP_INT_MAX * 2 + 1)."\n";
echo dechex(pow(2, 32) - 1)."\n";
```

The above example will output:

```
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
```

I am trying to reproduce that behaviour on a x64 system :

```
echo dechex(-1)."\n";
echo dechex(PHP_INT_MAX * 2 + 1)."\n";
echo dechex(pow(2, 64) - 1)."\n";
```

I am expecting :

```
ffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffff
```

But, I get :

```
ffffffffffffffff
0
0
```

Any idea in what's going on here?

Comment: It looks like `var_dump` do not return false: `string(16) "ffffffffffffffff"
string(1) "0"
string(1) "0"`

Comment: yeah, also tested and get same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's important to note that PHPs `dechex` function requires integer input.

On a 64bit system PHP does not have support for 64bit integers.

For example the typical `PHP_INT_MAX` on a 64 bit system is:

```
 9223372036854775807
```

This is also the maximum integer (!) number `dechex` can accept.

If you pass in `pow(2, 64) - 1` it's a float (`1.844674407371E+19`) which converted to integer is integer `0` hence `dechex` returns the string `"0"`.

Same applies if you pass in 2^64 as string `"18446744073709551615"`. It is converted to integer and it's integer value is `9223372036854775807` on 64 bit system. So dechex returns the string `"7fffffffffffffff"`.

Therefore if you need to deal with these numbers, you can not use PHP's integer type and therefore `dechex` is not the right tool for the job. Instead you can use bcmath and the gmp functions to achieve what you're looking for:

```
echo gmp_strval(bcadd(bcmul(2, PHP_INT_MAX), 1), 16), "\n";
echo gmp_strval(bcsub(bcpow(2, 64), 1), 16), "\n";
```

Comment: Okey, this make sense. Thanks! Strange that `dechex` doesn't give `false` when no conversion can be made.

Comment: This is because not `dechex` does the conversion but PHP. As it is loosely typed `dechex` only says it wants an integer and then PHP provides the integer (which then is 0 in your two unexpected cases). PHP does not give any warnings if type juggling results in loss of precision or triggers boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is a bug with dechex on a 64 bit platform  related to the fact that the largest integer that can be stored as a float is pow(2,53)-1 which is 9007199254740991.  The manual does warn about using really large numbers with base_convert because you can be working with floats and strange results can occur b/c of the imprecision of the floating point system. Something similar may be occurring with dechex.

PHP accepts a number as a parameter for dechex which may be either an integer or a float but the floats are in reality just a device for expressing whole numbers that overflow the boundaries of int.  The fact is that the code that you ran successfully on a 32 bit platform also passes to dechex a value that exceeds the maximum integer value for a 32 bit platform, passing in a float, as below comments indicate:

```
<?php

echo "Max int: ",PHP_INT_MAX, "\n"; // Max int: 2147483647
$num = (PHP_INT_MAX * 2) + 1;
var_dump($num);   //                // float(4294967295)
echo dechex($num),"\n";            // ffffffff
echo dechex(-1);                   // ffffffff
```

You may wish to file a bug report at bugs.php.net.